# Get basename of files in folder

Tags: bash, shell

I want to compress image files and wrote the following bash script:

`for i in *.png; do convert $i -quality 100% $i-comp.jpeg; done;`

When I run it I get filenames like `48.png-comp.jpeg`. I only want to have like `48-comp.jpeg`, so basically removing the `.png` part of the filename.

I tried using this `${$i/.png/}`, which gives me an error message.

Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: `${$i/.png/}` is almost correct, just remove the second `$` since it's not used inside a parameter expansion: `${i/.png/}`

Comment: @heitor I modified the script like that: `for i in *.png; do ${i/.png/}; convert $i -quality 88% $i-comp.jpeg; echo $i; done;` However, now the compression does not take place. I guess my current script is wrong. Any suggestion what is wrong?

Comment: You need to pass the new filename as an argument to `convert`: `convert "$i" -quality 88% "${i/.png}-comp.jpeg"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${$i/.png/}` is almost correct, but the second `$` is not needed inside a [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for i in *.png; do
  convert "$i" -quality 88% "${i/.png/}-comp.jpeg"
done
```

**Note:** `${i%.png}` is commonly more used to remove a file extension than `${i/.png/}`, but both should produce the same output.

Answer (score 1):

You could use parameter expansion to strip the png extension for the output file name:

```sh
for i in *.png; do convert $i -quality 100% ${i%.png}-comp.jpeg; done
```